# Does the path separator actually needs to be escaped in filter query but not in the facet prefix in solrj?

Tags: solr, solrj

In my java application powered by solrj I need to add [drill down](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#HierarchicalFaceting-DrillDown) function on the document paths which are tokenized at index time by the PathHierarchyTokenizer.

While researching why the expected results did not come up, I noticed that the path I wanted to search against needed to be properly java escaped in the fq parameter, ie "/" -> "/" ("\/" in java). So `query.toQueryString()` prints out `fq=path_descendent_path%3A%5C%2Fhome%5C%2Fuser1%5C%2FTestDir`.

So I am a bit confused because when escaping "/" the facet prefix does not work (facet count returns null) whereas without escaping "/" in the path, the correct counts are returned.

The full query that work is `select?q=test&q.op=AND&start=0&rows=10&defType=edismax&qf=contents_txt&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.field=path_descendent_path&facet.limit=-1&fq=path_descendent_path%3A%5C%2Fhome%5C%2Fuser1%5C%2FTestDir&f.path_descendent_path.facet.prefix=%2Fhome%2Fuser1%2FTestDir`.

Consequently I wonder if this is usual to use escaped path for the fq parameter and unescaped path in facet prefix or if I missed something ?

Please note : according to [lucene doc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters) "/" is a special character in Lucene as "`+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`" also are. But I have never needed to escape "[ ]" for example in fq parameter dealing with [date range](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html).

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo:/.../` is a regular expression pattern match. This works where a *query* is expected, such as the main query and the filter query (I'm not sure if it'd work in other arguments as it works on the token level iirc.)

The facet prefix is not a query - it's applied directly to match the front of the generated token.

Escaping in relation to date range - you would have to escape it if you expected it to be inside the *literal* part of the query. In a date range it's used as *syntax*.

Comment: Wow you've answered all my questions. Now that's crystal clear. Thanks a lot @MatsLindh!